# How to set column width of AspXGridView - EditForm?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

Has anybody got any idea for my purpose? How can we set the column width of AspXGridView's EditForm?

In editor properties there is only a Width property that is usefull when grid is table mode. But i want to change column width of one EditForm column.

Thanks.

Comment: which one EditMode are you using? http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditModes.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't control column width directly. You can use edit form template and use html table to organize controls.
Look at this [link](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S20232.aspx) for additional info.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the “PopupEditForm” mode, perform the following steps:

1) Specify the required EditForm’s Width via the ASPxGridView.SettingsEditing.PopupEditFormWidth property;

2) Organize a custom EditForm’s layout via the EditFormTemplate http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditFormTemplate.aspx;

3) Specify the required Width for a particular column and bind the column’s editor via two-way binding expression http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/TwoWayBinding.aspx.